# Cómo sumar números que hay dentro de un un fichero .txt en Shell Linux

Tags: linux, script, shell, shell-script

Se me ocurre sacarlos y meter cada número en una posición de un array para luego sumar lo contenido en todas las posiciones del array, pero tampoco sé cómo sacar cada número del fichero de texto y meterlo en el array.

Aunque si hubiese una forma de sumarlo directamente en el fichero o algo así pues mejor.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Yo te daré los métodos de como se podría realizar, pero esa parte te tocará hacerla a tí, y si una vez intentado no lo lograses, colgarías aquí el código para ir solucionando errores

Para leer un archivo de texto, el método sería;

```
while IFS= read -r line
    do
    #Aquí tocaría introducir el código de asignación de las líneas del fichero a las variables, suponiendo que haya un número en cada línea
    done < NombreArchivo.txt
```

Declaración de variables y asignación de valores:

```
#Declaramos variable A y le asignamos el valor 10
let A=10
#Declaramos variable B y le asignamos el valor 20
let B=20
#Declaramos variable C y le asignamos el valor de la suma de A + B
let C=$((A + B))

#Se imprimen los valores de las variables A, B y C
echo "A: $A | B: $B | C: $C"
```

Para darte alguna pista más, si por ejemplo queremos imprimir cada línea del fichero NombreArchivo.txt anterior, usaríamos la sentencia:

```
echo "$line"
```

Si deseas agregar texto a un fichero existente, utilizaríamos:

```
echo -e "Este es el resultado de la suma de A + B: $C" >> NombreArchivo.txt
```

También hablabas de array, la forma de declarar un array añadiendo valores (una de las formas, hay varias), sería:

```
valores[0]='10'
valores[1]='20'

valores[i]="$line"
```

Para imprimir todos los valores del array:

```
echo ${valores[@]}
```

Aunque si lo deseas haccer línea a línea con un bucle sería:

```
for i in "${valores[@]}"
    do
    echo $i
    done
```

Vamos!!!, inténtalo

Un saludo